# Scale an Array to min/max

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, given the following array

```
[-10, 5, 22, 54, 89, 152]
```

How would I go about getting a result like the following where there is a min of 0, and a max of 100. (this result is a guess, and not an actual reflection of what the numbers should look like)

```
[0, 8, 24, 53, 85, 100]
```

note: that the numbers in the middle also scale to fit.

Comment: What rounding method do you want to use? What have you tried? Hint: [`minmax`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) is a good place to start.

Comment: Adding 10 to each number and dividing it by 1.62 would give an array from 0 to 100, but the intermediate numbers would be quite different.

Comment: I've added a note that the expected result is simply a guess of what the numbers would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
def normalize(list, scale = 100)
  return unless (list.length >= 2)

  min, max = list.minmax

  range = max - min

  list.map do |v|
    ((v - min) * scale / range)
  end
end
```

This doesn't produce the same results as you expect, but I can't determine why you're expecting those results as scaling values linearly doesn't give those values. Here's some tests:

```
list = [-10, 5, 22, 54, 89, 152]

normalize(list)
# => [0, 9, 19, 39, 61, 100]

# Running it again changes nothing
normalize(normalize(list))
# => [0, 9, 19, 39, 61, 100]

list = [-1,0,1]

normalize(list)
# => [0, 50, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
ar = [-10, 5, 22, 54, 89, 152]
min = ar.min
range = ar.max - min
res = ar.map do |e|
  ((min - e).to_f / range).abs * 100
end
res
# => [0.0, 9.25925925925926, 19.753086419753085, 39.50617283950617, 61.111111111111114, 100.0]
```

You probably want to round these results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, i decided to shift the array so first element is at 0 and then figure out the scale:

```
def scale(a)
  shift = a.first * -1 if a.first != 0 || 0
  a.map! { |n| n + shift }
  return a if a.last == 100
  scale = a.last.to_f / 100.00
  a.map { |n| (n / scale).to_i }
end

puts scale([-10, 5, 22, 54, 89, 152]).inspect
puts scale([-10, 5, 22, 54, 89, 90]).inspect
puts scale([3, 5, 22, 54, 89, 90]).inspect
```

returns

```
[0, 9, 19, 39, 61, 100]
[0, 15, 32, 64, 99, 100]
[0, 2, 21, 58, 98, 100]
```